# Convergence in laws

Tags: probability, random-variables

i'm currently stuck in this exercice where i don't know how to start.

Let $\{X_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of independent random variables on $(\Omega, \mathbb{A}, \mathbb{P})$ with:

$$
F_{X_n}(t) = \left(1 - \frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)1_{[0,\infty)}(t)
$$

- for which $p \in (0,\infty)$ is $X_1$ in $L^p(\mathbb{P})$?
- Consider $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and the random variable:
  $$
  Z_n = min(\sqrt nX_1,\sqrt nX_2,...,\sqrt{n}X_n)
  $$

Show that $Z_n$ converges in law when $n \rightarrow \infty$ to a random variable with density f(x) that need to be determined.

$$
F_{X_1}(t) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 \le t) =  \left(1 - \frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)1_{[0,\infty)}(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^2}{1+t^2}dt
$$
$\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^p dt$ doesn't not converge for any p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_{X_n}$ is the distribution function of $X_n$, not the density function. Differentiation gives $f_{X_n}(t)=\frac {2t} {(1+t^{2})^{2}}$. Show that $E|X_1|^{p}=\int |t|^{p} f_{X_n}(t)dt <\infty$ iff $p <2$. Now
$P(Z_n >z)=(P(X_n >z /\sqrt n))^{n}=(\frac 1{1+z^{2}/n})^{n} \to e^{-z^{2}}$. Hence $Z_n \to Z$ in distribution where $P(Z>z) =e^{-z^{2}}$. Differentiate this to get the density of $Z$.